# Determine filesystem type without partition table

Tags: filesystems, partition

I have an old 16GB SCSI hard drive with some important files I'd like to backup. The problem is cfdisk doesn't recognize the hard drive, it says the partition table is zero. Another problem is, I don't know what kind of filesystem the drive had, so I'm a bit puzzled, how can I approach this delicate problem :P.

How can I determine the filesystem type? How can I repair the partition table? And what are some useful programs which can search the drive without a partition?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the disk originate from a SAN or a RAID setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition table.  It's available for many file systems.

Edit: It is advisable to run test disk in an image of the disk/partition you're trying to recover. 
To create that image, `dd` is your friend.